# how does garbage collection with respect to Strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, memory-leaks, garbage

I am reading about memory management in JVM and that if an object has no more references to it, it is garbage collected.
lets say, I have a program

```
public test {
  public static void main(String[ ] args) {
      String name = "hello";  
      for (int i =0 ; i < 5; i++) {
         System.out.println(i);
       }
   }
}
```

As you can see, the `String name` is not used anywhere, so its reference is kept through out and not garbage collected.

now I have,

```
String name = "hello"
  String name2 = name.substring(1,4)//"ell"
```

here again, the reference for `hello` must be present always, and cannot be garbage collected, since `name2` uses it.

so when do these `String` or any `objects` get garbage collected, which have references but are obsolete, i.e. no longer used in code?

I can see one scenario where trimming down an array causes memory leak and hence setting its reference to null is a good way to garbage collect those obsolete references.

Comment: Current versions of Java don't keep a reference to `name` in `name2`, in which case `name` can be freely collected.  Also, what do you mean by "trimming down an array"?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think he's talking about nulling out unused entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see one scenario where trimming down an array causes memory leak
>   and hence setting its reference to null is a good way to garbage
>   collect those obsolete references.

Strings are reference types, so all the rules for reference types with respect to garbage collection apply to strings.  The JVM may also do some optimizations on String literals but if you're worrying about these, then you're probably thinking too hard.

When does the JVM collect unreferenced objects?

The only answer that matters is: you can't tell and it needn't ever, but if it does you can't know when that will be.  You should never write Java code around deterministic garbage collection.  It is unnecessary and fraught with ugliness.

Speaking generally, if you confine your reference variables (including arrays or collections of reference types) to the narrowest possible scope, then you'll already have gone a long way toward not having to worry about memory leaks.  Long-lived reference types will require some care and feeding.

"Trimming" arrays (unreferencing array elements by assigning `null` to them) is **ONLY** necessary in the special case where the array represents your own system for managing memory, eg. if you are making your own cache or queue of objects.

Because the JVM can't know that your array is "managing memory" it can't collect unused objects in it that are still referenced but are expired.  In cases where an array represents your own system for managing memory, then you should assign `null` to array elements whose objects have expired (eg. popped off a queue; J. Bloch, Essential Java, 2nd Ed.).

Comment: when talking about scope, once the scope of an object is finished (with {}) are the references to it is lost??

Comment: As soon as a variable goes out of scope, it ceases to exist.  When a reference variable goes out of scope, its reference is immediately lost.  If the object which that variable referred to is not referenced any place else in the application, then it becomes "eligible for garbage collection" automatically.  In Visual Basic 5.0 it was necessary to carefully `null` out reference variables in order to prevent memory leaks, but this is unnecessary in Java and is considered bad practice, esp. if the variables are going to soon be out of scope anyway.

Comment: Say you have an array of reference types.  The array is, itself, a reference type.  If the array is referenced by only a single variable in the application -AND- the objects referred to by the array are not referenced any place else ... then when the reference variable goes out of scope, the array and all its objects automatically become eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: if I understand correctly, when a reference variable goes out of scope( there is no such thing as an Object going out of scope correct) and the object it references to is not used anywhere, then it is eligible for GC although it is still present in Heap?

Comment: Objects are kept in an area of memory called the Heap.  They are accessed by reference.  So in order to use an object, you need a variable that is holding a reference to it.  If an object is in the Heap, but there are no references to it, then it becomes eligible for garbage collection.  One doesn't usually talk about objects "going out of scope", but the variables holding their references most certainly can.  An object on the Heap with no references cannot be accessed and therefore cannot be used.  It can be garbage collected .. but you can't know when.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the JVM is not required to garbage-collect objects *ever*. In practice, they usually come behind a little while after the last reference is gone and free up the memory.

First, be aware that constants are always going to be around. Even if you assign a new value to `name`, the system still has a copy of `"hello"` stored with the class that it will reuse every time you hit that initializer statement.

However, don't confuse using an object for some sort of calculation with keeping a reference to it forever. In your second example, while `"hello"` is in fact kept around, that's just because it's living in the constant pool; `name2` doesn't have any sort of "hold" on it that keeps it in memory. The call to `substring` executes and finishes, and there's no eternal hold on `name`. (The actual implementation in the Oracle JVM shares the underlying `char[]`, but that's implementation-dependent.)

Clearing out arrays is a good practice because it's common for them to be long-lived and reused. If the entire array gets garbage collected, the references it holds get erased (and their objects garbage collected if those were the last ones).

Comment: when you say "constants are always going to be around", does it mean if i have `public  final Integer COUNT = 100`, does the `Integer` object remain forever?

Comment: Yes. In fact, even if you only have a field initializer (`private Integer count = 0;`), the `Integer` object there will stay around as long as the class itself is in scope. (Actually, in JVMs on full computers, `Integer`s for -128..127 are always kept around anyway for speed.)

Answer (score 0):

Every variable in Java has a scope: The piece of code during which the variable is defined. The scope of a local variable like `name` in your example is between the brackets `{}` it is in. Thus, the `name` variable will be defined when the thread reaches the `String name = "hello";` declaration, and will be kept alive until the `main` method is finished (because then the brackets the variable was in are closed).

Strings are a different story though than other variables. Strings are cached internally and may not actually be made available for the garbage collector yet.